# Пропускать ячейки с Null

Tags: c#, mysql

Если в таблице есть хотя бы одна запись null то combobox не выводит результат.
Как мне выдать только ячейки где есть записи?

```
public void combobox()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConString.ToString());
                string s = "SELECT * FROM zapros";
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(s, conn);
                MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString("Системы"));
                    }

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Вероятно вы имели в виду "в таблице", а не "в базе". И вообще, заголовок говорит о том, что вы хотите отображать пустые значения, а по тексту следует обратное. Уточните, пожалуйста суть вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в коде проверить

```
public void combobox()
    {
         try
         {
              MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConString.ToString());
              string s = "SELECT * FROM zapros";
              conn.Open();
              MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(s, conn);
              MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
              while (dr.Read())
              {
                   if (!dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Системы")))
                {
                    var tmp = dr.GetString("Системы");

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(tmp);
                }
              }
              conn.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          } 
     }
```

Comment: не работает. Ошибка "Неопределенные данные. Этот метод или свойство не может вызываться для значений равных Null"

Comment: попробуйте tmp != DBNull.Value

Comment: не помогло выдаёт такую же ошибку

Comment: А если использовать  if(!dr.IsDBNull(tmp))

Comment: тоже самое Неопределенные данные итд

Comment: !dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Системы"))

Comment: Всё заработало нужно было сделать так  if (!dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Системы")))
                    {
                        var tmp = dr.GetString("Системы");

                        comboBox1.Items.Add(tmp);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Используйте проверку на непустоту:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield IS NOT NULL
```

Есть важный нюанс: результат выражения над значением NULL всегда равен NULL.
Например (NULL > 0) равно NULL и (NULL <= 0) равно NULL, поэтому проверка провалится в любом случае. Выручают специальные выражения (x IS NULL) и (x IS NOT NULL).

В некоторых случаях требуется проверять как на NULL, так и на "пустое" в терминах вашей бизнес логики. Типа:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (myfield IS NOT NULL) AND (myfield > 0)
```

Выше я написал почему одного только myfield > 0 будет недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

я с с# не работал, но  попробуйте дописать в запрос условие where переменная is not null

Comment: не работает( точнее в phpmyadmin работает а в программе нет(

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема в null ? Пробовали в тестовой БД убирать все значения с null в базе? Если убрать начинает работать? Системы это столбик в БД, условие where is null на него прописывали?

Comment: Пробовал, тогда всё работает нормально

Comment: Если прописать так в phpmyadmin SELECT * FROM `zapros` WHERE `Системы` IS NOT NULL то работает но если в программе то получаю Could not find specified column in results: SELECT * FROM `zapros` WHERE `Системы` IS NOT NULL